# Keras ImageDataGenerator flow directory with 3D CNN data format error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new in Keras, I have a dataset with multiple folders each indicates to a specific class. I used ImageDataGenerator to read the data from the subfolders.
I am trying to use 16 consecutive frames with size 80x100 so the input_shape is (16, 80, 100, 1).
When I do the training there is an error about the input of the network, I know that the input should 5d tensor for 3D CNN but I am not sure if I doing this correctly.

I am using spyder to write and implement the code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv3D, MaxPooling3D
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.optimizers import SGD, RMSprop
from keras.utils import np_utils, generic_utils
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import os
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import preprocessing

datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_data=datagen.flow_from_directory('C:\\Users\\AA\\Data\\Training', target_size=(80, 100), color_mode='grayscale', classes=None, class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32, interpolation='nearest')
test_data=datagen.flow_from_directory('C:\\Users\\AA\\Data\\Testing', target_size=(80, 100), color_mode='grayscale', classes=None, class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32, interpolation='nearest')



    ins = (16, 80, 100, 1)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), input_shape=ins, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3), border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3), border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))


 model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])    


   model.fit_generator(train_data,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=test_data,
        validation_steps=800)
```

The error says:

```py
File "C:\Users\AA\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 113, in _standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv3d_24_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 80, 100, 1)
```

Comment: Any useful note about that !

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the `ImageDataGenerator`.

It only works for images, not for videos (I got the same error and at https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10150 they also claim that `ImageDataGenerator` only works for image-shaped-tensors. There they also suggest to implement your own data-generation like described in https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly.html, but I haven't tried this myself)

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/Emadeldeen-24/736c33ac2af0c00cc48810ad62e1f54a

Here is a custom imagedatagenerator for 5D input to Conv3D nets. Hope it helps.

```
from tweaked_ImageGenerator_v2 import ImageDataGenerator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_data=datagen.flow_from_directory('path/to/data', target_size=(x, y), batch_size=32, frames_per_step=4)
```

Comment: The link is updated to https://gist.github.com/Emadeldeen24/736c33ac2af0c00cc48810ad62e1f54a

Answer (score 0):

The model is interpreting your input as 16 samples of 80x100 greyscale images. You must reshape the input as

```
(no_of_samples,16,80,100,1)
```

Here 16 are your timesteps

Comment: thanks for reply, is the number of samples the train_data itself? as I tried to reshape the train_data but still error happen even when I use the same reshape function. Or should I write this structure in the input as: ins = (no_of_samples,16,80,100,1) .. Thanks

Comment: yea I mean if you have 32 images, then you will have 2 sequences of 16  frames. So your shape will be (2,16,80,100,1). So you will have to reshape it. Just that you will have to take care about getting the sequences right as you do not have control over the order of ImageDataGenerator

Comment: I have tried to change the input shape to (samples, 80, 100, 16, 1) but there is an error that expecting 5d but found 6d. Also I tried to use XX = (train_data.samples, 80, 100, 16, 1) and there is an error says tuple objects is not an iterator. I have tried to do the same found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699956/3d-convolutional-neural-network-input-shape but there is no way to reshape the train_data!!

Comment: user239457, I forgot to mention that samples = 193

Comment: Guys how could I reshape it? I just stuck with this error I did test it with 2D conv and it works properly.